# Border radius Sass Mixin

Tags: css, sass, mixins

At the time i use 2 Mixins for my Border Radius:

```
// When the Input is 1 Variable
@mixin border-radius($pixel) {
  border-radius: $pixel;
}

// When the Inputs are 4 Variables
@mixin border-radius-s($tl, $tr, $br, $bl) {
  border-top-left-radius: $tl;
  border-top-right-radius: $tr;
  border-bottom-right-radius: $br;
  border-bottom-left-radius: $bl;
}
```

I'm trying to find a way to combine those mixins in to one! Probably with an `if else` for the input. I've tried around but couldn't find any good working solution.

Anyone that could help me on that ?

Comment: To be fair, you do not need to prefix `border-radius`, and you most surely do not support browsers which require vendor prefixes (see [support table](http://caniuse.com/border-radius)). It basically just wastes bandwidth for all of your clients.

Comment: My problem is how to combine 2 mixins into 1 :). I'm trying to find a way for me to write `@include border-radius(3px)` and the output would be `border-radius: 3px`, and if i write `@include border-radius(3px, 2px, 3px, 2px)` etc.

Comment: I mean besides the fact you pointed out :)

Comment: Oh ok, my comment was just a side-note. Your code looks cleaner now without that clutter. `=]` Well, let's see, you basically want to overload the mixin to accept either 1 or 4 arguments then.

Comment: That's exactly what i'm trying to do =)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can set the mixin to accept a list of values, as shown [in the docs](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#variable_arguments).

```
@mixin border-radius($pixel...) {
  border-radius: $pixel;
}
```

Comment: That gives me an output of `border-radius: 1px, 2px, 3px, 4px`. For Box shadows it may be good but for the border radius where i need the other variables as well..

Comment: `@include border-radius(10px 5px 20px 10px);` works for me, +1

Comment: Oh, i missed the commas =p.. Thanks

Comment: Though, in this case, without using prefixes, it is the same as not using a mixin. Just to note.